# Class cast of the variable inside loop

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I've got a simple json:

> {"someparam1":[1,2,3],"someparam2":[1,2,3],...}

in order to parse I use this code:

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else { return }
for key in json.allKeys{
                guard let array = json[key] as? [Int] else { return }
                minemap[key] = array
            }
```

where `fileprivate var minemap: [String : [Int]] = [:]`
But the compiler says that `minemap[key]` is incorrect!
So I want to cast `key` to `String`. But what is the most beautiful solution to do something like this :

`for key as? String in json.allKeys`
?

Comment: Why `NSDictionary`? Use a proper Swift dictionary with proper types.

Comment: What is `minemap`? Your question talks about `transitmap`.

Comment: @rmaddy , fixed. What would you suggest to parse json?

Comment: @rmaddy , i've only worked with NSDictionary

Comment: Open up the Swift book and learn about Swift native collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `[String: [Int]]` instead `NSDictionary`, cast once and avoid all further casts.

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as?[String: [Int]] else { return }
minemap = json
```

This may not work, if not all values have the type `[Int]`. If that is the case, use `[String: Any]` instead and cast the values later.

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as?[String: Any] else { return }
for (key, value) in json {
    minemap[key] = json[key] as? [Int]
}
```